# How to add video of more than 15 MB size on force.com site

Tags: force.com-sites, static-resources

I'm creating a force.com site. There is one video on my VisualForce page. Now I have to upload that video as a static resource, the but video is more than 15 MB in size. I have to put that video on my website.

How can I add this video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload the video on some other https server or a video hosting platform like [Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/) or [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/), and reference it on the site using an `iframe`. Since you are anyway exposing it in a public site, there's no harm in uploading the video and exposing it via an `iframe`.

YouTube gives you a video iframing code snippet like that shown below. You can use it on your VisualForce page.

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" 
width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/W-Q7RMpINVo"
frameborder="0" allowFullScreen>
</iframe>
```